# Bibliography on Industrial Policy

Tags: industrial-organisation

I'm looking for an introduction to Industrial Policy, at the advanced undergraduate level, beginning graduate level.

I've tried the google scholar, and unfortunately all the results I read were just isolated papers, and one or two handbooks... No textbook, though.

It seems to me that Industrial Policy, in the western (USA/GB)  economic tradition has been cornered into a small subset of Industrial Organization, and a matter which is best left to the 'unregulated' market. Am I correct?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=industrial+policy&btnG=&oq=industrial+poli)?

Comment: @HerrK. I'm sorry for my last comment... It was undeserving. I should have been more tactful. Thanks for the Google Scholar link. ;)